# using <ratio> without typedef

Tags: c++, c++11, typedef

I was always told that `typedef` is used for simplify things or shorten names. I mean, we can do things without it. But today I tried to use `<ratio>` library and I don't know how to do things without using `typedef`.

Here's simple example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ratio>    // C++11

int main()
{
    const int   a = 1, b = 17;
    typedef     std::ratio<a,b> p;

    std::cout << "Number p = " << p::num << "/" << p::den << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

How can I do the same without using `typedef`?

Comment: doesn't `std::ratio<a,b>::num` and `std::ratio<a,b>::den` work? Also, `typedef` is not just to simplify things. Sometimes it's used to give meaning to a type. For example `typedef int priority;` and later `priority p1, p2;`. Another very popular use-case of `typedef` is for abstraction. For example, in one system you may have `typedef int sig_atomic_t;` and another definition in another system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need a typedef:

```
int main() {
    const int a = 1, b = 17;
    std::ratio<a,b> p;

    std::cout << "Number p = " << p.num << "/" << p.den << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to create a variable, do it as others have mentioned:

```
std::cout << "Number p = " << std::ratio<a,b>::num << "/" << std::ratio<a,b>::den << std::endl;
```

Comment: So I can just use dot? Thanks, `p.num` works :) When I tried to reffer by `::` I had error C2510 that  'p' : left of '::' must be a class/struct/union

Comment: In the first example I create a variable `p` of type `ratio`. In the second, anonymous `ratio` objects are created each time.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp actually, in the second time you are accessing `static const` members of the class `std::ratio<a,b>` (not of any object of the class).

Comment: @Massa I didn't realize the `num` and `den` are `static`.

Answer (score 1):

you can just do

```
std::ratio<a,b>::num
```

if you don't want to use typedef

Answer (score 1):

In [`std::ratio`,](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio) `num` and `den` are member objects not types. Therefore you can't `typedef` them.*<sup>†</sup>* Since those members are `constexpr` you can use them without any object like `ratio<a,b>::num`.

*<sup>†</sup><sub>Type of `num` and `den` is `std::intmax_t`. To make your legal type, you can use `typedef decltype(ratio<a,b>::num) t;` which is far from what you want and useless.</sub>*